# transfer a simple text to json

Tags: json, scripting

How to convert a simple text to json programmatically using linux script bash or any other scripting language !

Raw text was like this :

```
Question 1 ?
Answer1,answer2,answer3{C},answer4
Question 2 ?
{C}Answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
Question 3 ?
Answer1,answer2{C},answer3,answer4
...
```

Actually I succeeded to convert it , but now  I need to update correct value to the right answer number tagged by {C} for every question !

```
{
    "introduction":"My Quiz", 
    "questions":[
{"question":"Question 1?", 
        "answers":["answer1","answer2","answer3{C}","answer4"],
        "correct":2},
{"question":"Question 2?", 
        "answers":["{C}answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],
        "correct":2}
    ]
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could show the input, how you are currently converting it (the Perl code), and what you need the end result to be. It looks like you are close, but it is very hard to tell what you have done wrong if you just give the output of your script.

Comment: I convert it only using gedit by find and replace

Comment: the RAW text was like this :                                 Question1 \n answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4 \n Question2 \n answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4 \n ...

Comment: Post the RAW text in your question using code tags.

Comment: I need some kind of script to edit this file !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my ($correctans) = grep {s/.*(\d).*/$1/ if m/C/} (my @answers = qw({C}Answer1 answer2 answer3{C} answer4));
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! is this a perl code, how can I use it ?

Comment: yes this is perl code. The concept is that you use a regular expression to identify the word containing the Capital C letter, then extract the attached digit. In your script you would place this after you have processed the `answers` variable but before you process the `correct` variable.

Comment: can you write me a demo of this perl code that I could  execute it directly in linux console. let's say my file named Questions.json !

Comment: how can I use this code in linux console (perl installed) to write the results in the file Questions.json !

Comment: @saad: That seems like you are stuck on basic use of Perl - how to write a short script - which is not really what your first question was about. One assumption on Stack Overflow is that you can use or are learning the language that you are asking about. If you are starting from very little Perl knowledge then it may take you a day to learn enough basics to write short scripts (with help on any difficult bits like this regular expression). If you want to use Perl for other short scripts that will be a day well spent.

Comment: I make it , thank you !